# Enclosing the content of a text file in element tags and writing the output to an XML file

Tags: command-line, dos

How can I prepend a start-tag to the content of a text file, append it with an end-tag and redirect the output to an XML file in command line?

Comment: What commandline? What shell? DOS? Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DOS:

```
echo "<tag>"  > file.xml
type file.txt >> file.xml
echo "</tag>" >> file.xml
```

`>` will create the file, or truncate it if it exists, and `>>` will append to it.

Comment: You could put those 3 lines in a `.bat` file and call that.